# Multiple questions regarding formatting tables

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

**Question 1**

A while ago, I used some code from here, which fitted my requirements perfectly. However, I'd like a different table, and playing around with the code (I'm quite new to Latex) has not yielded any encouraging results. Basically I'd like a table like the one below (produced in Excel because I can't produce it in Latex at the moment):

[image]

Currently I am getting the following - note the numbers in notes are from an old table

[image]

My MWE (don't worry about alignment when it appears in the article class - I'm using a customised template which already has all the margins etc set out). I'd also like the Notes column to have a slightly greater width than the other columns because I will be putting more text in there. Also you might notice the (See Appendix ??) - that is my second question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Description of Independent Variables}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.20\textwidth}*{4}{L{\dimexpr0.20\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
\toprule
& {\bfseries Independent Variable} & {\bfseries Code} & {\bfseries Units} &    \bfseries{Notes} \\
\midrule
First-year GPA & FYGPA & Continuous & Overall first-year Grade Point Average & 5 -- 6  \\
Adjusted Matric GPA & AMGPA & Continuous & The average includes the top four subjects,  excluding Mathematics, Additional Mathematics, Mathematics Paper 3 and English (First or Second Language. See Appendix~\ref{chapter:AppendixB}). & 11 -- 14 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Question 2**

I have a 'chapter' which is actually an Appendix. I've labelled the Appendix in the following way:

```
\chapter{Appendix B}
\label{AppendixB}
\lhead{Appendix B \emph{Adjusted Matric GPA }}
```

Now when I wanted to cross-reference this Appendix in my text, I get a ??. My cross-reference is the following:

```
See Appendix~\ref{chapter:AppendixB})
```

Why is Latex not picking up the label?

**Question 3**

My table is going to extend over one page once I put all my variables in. I see the longtable package is recommended for this job. However, simply replacing the \begin{table}...\end{table} with \begin{longtable}...\end{longtable} in my MWE is bringing up a whole host of additional errors (for example, it doesn't like the \centering command and says \caption -> \noalign). What should I be aware of when using the longtable package over the table package?

Comment: Question 2 is easy: Use correct label in the referense, i.e. "Appendix~\ref{AppendixB}. Or better: use the ‘cleveref’-package. ‘longtable’ is centered by default. Remove the \centering-command. Also, remove the table-environment. You set the caption within the longtable it self. Read the documentation.

Comment: Interesting. A bit confusing as it is a "chapter", so to speak. Will read the documentation.

Comment: Question 3: You basically replace `tabular` by `longtable` and leave out the `table` environment completely. In some sense `longtable` implements both environments at once and has its own support for captions; see the documentation.

Comment: Reference is not confusing: In standard LaTeX you repeat the label, letter by letter, inside the brackets: You mix this with the the fact that many LaTeX-user use the refernce type in the label name: \label{chapter:AppendixB} "see Appendix~ \ref{chapter:AppendixB}"

Comment: And in addition to @StephanLehmke comment: Set up a normal preamble to the table: Stat with {llll}. When the table compiles, then start to refine the column width - one by one. The same goes with other formatting. Apply formatting as the last touch, after you have populated the table and are sure that everything works. Them apply the formatting - one after one.

Comment: Ok cool, after some experimenting I think I got it. Can't seem to cross-reference a longtable though. I have this in my longtable code:
\caption{Description of Independent Variables \label{DIV}} \\

I have this in my code:
A description of the independent variables used in this analysis is presented in Table~\ref{table:DIV} below.

@Sveinung - yes, thanks for the advice. I jumped the gun a bit there.

Comment: @Chris Put the label outside the last bracket in the caption: \caption{Description ...}\label{DIV}, and use correct label name:  "A description of the ... in Table~\ref{DIV} below"

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `ltablex` package, that extends `longtable` to the `tabularx environment. I don't know what you want to do with a`threeparttable`environment (you don't really use it here), but anyway, it doesn't work with longtables. For long tables, you have to load the`threeparttablex`package, and the environment is`ThreePartTable`.

To cross-reference, you have to put a label just after the caption. I think this code fulfills all your requirements:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry} %
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.25\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.75\hsize}X}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand*{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\theadalign}{{C}c}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{2}{C}*{2}{L}@{}}
\caption{Description of Independent Variables}\\
\toprule
& \thead{Independent \\ Variable} & \thead{Code} & \thead{Units} &    \thead{Notes} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\itshape continued}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
First-year GPA & FYGPA & Continuous & Overall first-year Grade Point Average & 5 -- 6  \\
Adjusted Matric GPA & AMGPA & Continuous & The average includes the top four subjects,  excluding Mathematics, Additional Mathematics, Mathematics Paper 3 and English (First or Second Language. See Appendix~\ref{chapter:AppendixB}). & 11 -- 14 \\
First-year GPA & FYGPA & Continuous & Overall first-year Grade Point Average & 5 -- 6  \\
Adjusted Matric GPA & AMGPA & Continuous & The average includes the top four subjects,  excluding Mathematics, Additional Mathematics, Mathematics Paper 3 and English (First or Second Language. See Appendix~\ref{chapter:AppendixB}). & 11 -- 14 \\
First-year GPA & FYGPA & Continuous & Overall first-year Grade Point Average & 5 -- 6  \\
First-year GPA & FYGPA & Continuous & Overall first-year Grade Point Average & 5 -- 6  \\
Adjusted Matric GPA & AMGPA & Continuous & The average includes the top four subjects, excluding Mathematics, Additional Mathematics, Mathematics & 11 -- 14 \\
 &  & & Paper 3 and English (First or Second Language. See Appendix~\ref{chapter:AppendixB}). & %\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\appendix
\section{First Appendix}
\section{Second Appendix} \label{chapter:AppendixB}
\end{document}
```

[image]